# Preload custom module python vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Does the new python language server available in Visual Studio Code based on the Visual Studio one allows for the preload module option.

`"python.autoComplete.preloadModules": []`

And if it does indeed work with it, does it work with project modules or only modules installed in the virtualenv?

Doing something like `"python.autoComplete.preloadModules": ["/path/to/module"]` would work on the any of both implementations?

Answer (score 0):

You can add them like below

```
"python.autoComplete.preloadModules": ["numpy", "pandas", "matplotlib"],
```

also, check the docs! :)

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_autocomplete-and-intellisense

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I was referring to custom created modules. Lets say I have some big custom code in `/path/to/code`that I want to preload. Would that work with that option? I'm not referring to those modules installed by pypi, which all examples show.

Comment: my interpretation of the docs suggests you'd include those in `python.autoComplete.extraPaths` but I think we'd have to test it to know for certain

Comment: I already have those modules included in extraPaths and autocompletion works fine with them. I'm looking to bump the load times a bit by preloading them, but the documentation doesn't seems to say this anywhere.

Comment: Most of what google gives me is related to load times. If you haven't already check out this issue https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/issues/581 . At the bottom it suggests that if you disable the jedi engine/language server (`"python.jediEnabled": false`) which will enable the new Microsoft python IntelliSense engine http://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2018/07/18/introducing-the-python-language-server/

Comment: With the new Python Language Server in VSCode, this option is deprecated. I don't know the correct one now.